# Global Jquery Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, validation

I need help. I have a validation function written in jQuery in a separate .js file and html code in a separate aspx page.

Now I want to implement my jQuery validation like this `(#mobile).validate();` from my .aspx page, so that the validation for textbox for moblile will take place.

I am also posting the code for reference. I would be thankful if I get any help/hints on this issue. I do not want to use jquery.validate.js.

Thanks,
Dipak

### FormValidation.js

```
$('#' + mobile).bind('keypress', function (e) {
return (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) ? false : true;
})

function InitValidate(btnsubmit, name, email, mobile) {
var Isvalid = true;
$(btnsubmit).click(function () {

    var Isvalid = true;

    if ($(name).val() == '') {
        alert('Name cannot be blank')
        Isvalid = false;
    }
    else {
        if ($(email).val() == '') {
            alert('Name Email be blank')
            Isvalid = false;
        }
        if (!IsEmail(email)) {
            alert("Invalid email address.");
            Isvalid = false;
        }
        if ($(mobile).val() == '') {
            alert('Name mobile number be blank')
            Isvalid = false;
        }
    }

    return Isvalid;
});
})
```

### Default.aspx

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var name = $('#<%= name.ClientID %>');
        var email = $('#<%= email.ClientID %>');
        var mobile = $('#<%= mobile.ClientID %>');
        var btnsubmit = $('#<%= btnsubmit.ClientID %>');

        InitValidate(btnsubmit, name, email, mobile);
    });
    var mobile = '<% =mobile.ClientID%>';
    (#mobile).validate();
</script>
```

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div>
            <span>First Name</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>E-Mail ID</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Mobile Number</span>
            <asp:TextBox ID="mobile" runat="server" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnsubmit" Text="submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script src="Script/FormValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: `(#mobile).validate();` in invalid `#mobile` needs to be a string for starters e.g. `$('#mobile').validate();` or `$('#' + mobile).validate();` in your case. That code also needs to be inside the DOM ready event handler.

Comment: As you seem to be having some basic problems with jQuery, doing your own validation seems "a little bold". Why don't you want to use a standard validation package like jquery.validate.js?

Comment: I started converting your example to a JSFiddle and there are *a lot* of problems with the code. Too many to list in comments, but some prevent an answer being written.

Comment: Here's a partially fixed test JSFiddle for others to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/mhw34uz6/4/